# How to run Selenium script recorded in Firefox plugin with console output?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

We have a requirement to run selenium script recorded in fire fox plugin via tool which can run these scripts and give logs on a web console. Does anyone know of such a tool?
Requirement is that QA guy records a bunch of test cases and then some non tech person can simply come in and run these and see verbose output.

Comment: Have a look at `Selenium IDE` http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following plugin for Selenium-IDE to save log to a file.

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for record playback too, this would be a better option. 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

They have plugin for chrome as well, so hopefully you can use run the same recorded scripts in chrome browser as well.